Uninstalling Anaconda MacOS .bash_profile
Fairly new to the world of code, downloaded anaconda on my MacOS a while ago but want to start afresh. I've removed the application and emptied from bin and done rm -rf ~/anaconda3 , also removed the hidden files.
Having trouble editing ~/.bash_profile and removing the anaconda directory from PATH environment variable. When running vim ~/.bash_profile , I get the following output:
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
source ~/.profile.bash_profile
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.bash_profile" 

Unsure how to proceed from here and would appreciate any guidance please. The conda command doesn't work either, probably because I have deleted associated files but for some reason 'conda intialize' remains.
conda activate
conda init --reverse --all

received the message 'conda command not found'

Just remove every line from "# >>> conda initialize >>>" through "# <<< conda initialize <<<", both ends included.

You can use sed:
sed -i.ori '/# >>> conda initialize >>>/,/# <<< conda initialize <<</d' ~/.bash_profile

to delete the block.
Original file will be stored as .ori in case you need it.
